# Sending SharePoint Alerts programmatically using Client Side Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-alerts

I'm wondering if it is possible to send a SharePoint Alert programmatically using CSOM.

I'm creating an app, and it would be useful if I could use JavaScript to send messages to users, but it doesn't seem to me that there is a way to set up Alerts without having the user manually click "Alert Me" and set up the alerts themselves.

If it definitively can't be done I'd like to know, so I can look into other approaches.

Comment: If sending emails (not in the form of an alert) fits your needs, you could use the solution found here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92062/how-to-send-email-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can add a custom Alert:

1. Override **CustomAlertTemplates**.xml and implement **InotifyHandler**.
2. You can create a custom control in ribbon and add custom code for it.
3. Easiest one would be add a custom web-part(CE,SE) and write your custom logic for it.

Comment: Hi, Once I add CE/SE, Can I add items to 'default Alert list' using JSOM?